# Capturing response with a JQuery modal dialogue

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog, confirmation

I have a simple confirm dialogue:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function confirmPubGL( theForm )
        {
            theForm.submit.disabled = true;
            var r=confirm('Are you sure you want to press the OK button?')
            if (r==true)
            {
                alert('Submitting form data now.');

            } else {
                alert('Nothing happened.')
                theForm.submit.disabled = false;
            }

        }
    </script>   

    <form name='abc' id='abc' method='post' action='feedme.php' onSubmit="return confirmPubGL(this)">
        <input type=hidden name=action  value='submitme'>
        <input type=submit name='submit' value='Click Me!'>
    </form>
```

I'd like to spruce this up using JQuery's [dialogues](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).  The examples look great, but I'm not seeing how to use this in an existing form.  I'm fairly new to JQuery, so it maybe something ridiculously easy I'm overlooking.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Do it!": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>


    <form name='abc' id='abc' method='post' action='feedme.php' onSubmit="return WhatDoIDoHere()">
        <input type=hidden name=action  value='submitme'>
        <input type=submit name='submit' value='Click Me!'>
    </form>

<div id='dialog-confirm' title='Submit Data?'>
<p><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-alert' style='float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;'></span>You are about to submit data. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
```

What would I need to change in order to properly incorporate JQuery's Confirmation example with the form above?

Comment: Do you want to show the jQuery UI dialog after you confirm dialog?

Comment: are you still using the normal form submit action? or are you going to change to using ajax?

Comment: I don't need ajax for this form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Do it!": function() {
                    var confirmMsg = "Are you sure?";
                    if (confirm(confirmMsg)) {
                        // Send your form
                    } else {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, my mistake in latter answer. I didn't understand your question.

```
<script>
    function WhatDoIDoHere() {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
    }
</script>
```

Hope this answer your question.

Comment: How do I invoke the jquery dialogue from the form?  In the first example the old confirm() dialogue is invoked from onSubmit in the <form> tag.

Comment: You just added a confirm box to the replacement confirm dialog...  He want's to replace using confirm box with the dialog

Comment: Pretty sure I have something else wrong with this. Error console not showing errors, but the dialog box isn't working right. http://jsfiddle.net/G8x2k/1/

Comment: I'd like to select your answer, but am not sure it works.  Can you please take a look at the fiddle right above?

Comment: First of all, you can disable autoOpen property of jQuery dialog writting `autoOpen: false`. Then, I think your problem is that when you submit your form, they reload the page. Try using a html button to open your dialog form.